# How can I preserve my redux (redux-saga) data without display/store in local or session storage on page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Please checkout the below files where is setup my redux store.
**configureStore.js file**

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
  const composeEnhancers =
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

  const logger = store => next => action => {
    let result = next(action)
    try {
      const fullState = store.getState()
      localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(fullState));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("localStorage set error:", e)
    }
    return result
  }

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, logger))
  )
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

  return store
}
```

Please check the root **index.js** file where I want to restore my redux info on application load

```
let initialState = {}
try {
// set redux data in initial state
  initialState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("state")) || {};
} catch (e) {
  console.error("localStorage get error:", e)
}
const store = configureStore(initialState)

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
      <Loader />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```

Please help me out from this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm wondering if there is another way to persist redux data. will you explain how you came across such a situation?

Comment: @TopW3  I have some secure data which use in whole application and will not visible to client from front-end side. so I need to persist data with redux store.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try out redux-persist for this.

https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/the-definitive-guide-to-redux-persist-84738167975